# How to get url parameter value in Microsoft team tab

Tags: c#, microsoft-teams

I am creating one Microsoft team app, where I need to display value from URL parameter to team Tab. can any one help me to solve it.

example Url: msteams://teamurl?targeturl=websiteUrl

so I want the value of targetUrl in to my tab.

Comment: I can't follow your question properly. Do you have an app with a tab already? Are you trying to get something from the Teams context (i.e. this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/access-teams-context)?

Comment: Yes, i already have a app with tab where i want to display value from url parameter. I have check the teams context but i want some extra parameter which does not exist in context or i want any parameter at context which i can set from url and get it on my app team tab.

Comment: You haven't described your scenario completely, so it's hard to advise (like where is the extra parameter coming from, for example), but you can't change the context - the only way to get an "extra" parameter is via Deep Linking - perhaps that can do what you're looking for? See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/deep-links .

Comment: thank you for the reply, My scenario is that i have a link button in my own website where i have specified link to my team tab. where i want one more extra parameter like 'targetUrl' which i want to get it's value in My Tab.

Comment: ahh, I see now - so you're wanting to deep link, but from an -external- link. I -think- you might be able to do something like that, using the "subentity" option (see here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/deep-links#generating-a-deep-link-to-your-tab). I'll try post a full answer below (for more space)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comments, the idea here is to get a deep link, but from an *external* application. I haven't ever done this, so this is just conjecture, but I can suggest an option that might work:

1. First, see how the "subentity" element works, [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/deep-links#generating-a-deep-link-to-your-tab).
2. Then, try test that from -within- your tab, but do it using Teams from within the browser.
3. Once it renders, right click and go (in Chrome) "view page source". This will load a new tab, showing the full URL
4. That should give you an idea of how to populate the "context" section, specifically the 'subEntityId', which you can access from the Teams context in javascript.

Like I said, this is untested, but it might do what you need.

Comment: Thanks for the response in detail. I have check the sub entity elements and get the links to open my tab directly but I have not seen any parameter where i can pass my values. Still I have try by using "subEntityWebUrl" and some others but It can not not get it in my Tab.  Sample Url i have used.

https://teams.microsoft.com/l/entity/<APPID>/_djb2_msteams_prefix_3424722300?context={"subEntityId"="com.contoso.helloworld.hellotab","subEntityWebUrl"="https://abc.comp3d.in","channelId"=<chanelId>}&groupId=<groupid>&tenantId=<tenantid>

Comment: Based on your post i have found the solution for this. Now I get my parameter value in subEntityId field. So For all of the developer who is looking for the parameter to pass extra value  from external website to tab then he can do it in subEntityId which you can get in your tab from context by microsoftTeams.getContext method.

Comment: great stuff, glad I could help